# Decoding base64 encoded message with a key

Tags: hash, encoding

I am pentesting a database that where I found data which was base64 encoded. I tried the usual method of decoding `base64`, which didn't work.

Later, I found in database a field called `base64_custom_key`. How do I decrypt a base64 encoded message with a key?

For eg.
The key looks like `gP9jOzA75VyIW6FRuHZimQcLB1rCTKpGN8hdEXw0eY3kMx+/JDUntsob4a2qfSv` and the value generated looks like `ucaUCo4NmA88Tws8BoQsKAXdBcDn`

Comment: This question clearly asks **how** to decrypt such a block of data guys, it only includes the block of data as example. I've seen this type of "encryption" before and I think it is valuable to explain that it's a substitution cipher and how to decrypt it.

Comment: I don't see the reason to put it on hold. Moderators, care to explain? This isn't about analyzing a specific cipher.

Comment: I think the fact that this is a classical substitution cipher that has been applied in modern time to perform some kind of obfuscation has something to do with it, Abhi. Taht's however not a good close reason.

Comment: I would look at this page....just input your information and you will get your results https://www.malwaretracker.com/decoder_base64.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a simple substitution cipher. Base 64 uses the following alphabet `A-Za-z0-9+/`. Here `A` encodes  `000000`, `B` encodes `000001` etc. In your case the `g` encodes `000000`, `P` encodes `000001` etc.

Instead of writing your own decoder for that you can simply take the ciphertext, iterate through the characters of the ciphertext and replace `g` with `A`, `P` with `B` etc. After that you should be able to use a regular base 64 decoder to do the work for you.

Don't replace multiple characters at a time or you'll run into trouble. Put the characters in a new string instead (if you map `g` to `A` while there are still other `A` characters left then your algorithm will certainly fail).

Comment: Note that this should be considered "toy encryption".

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This clearly is a non standard way of encrypting something. :)

Comment: Note that many programming languages / environments include a built-in tool for such character replacement, e.g. `tr///` for Perl, `strtr()` for PHP, `string.translate()` for Python, etc. Many of these are modeled on the Unix command-line tool [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29). In particular, to decode your example string using Unix tools, just run the command `echo ucaUCo4NmA88Tws8BoQsKAXdBcDn | tr 'gP9jOzA75VyIW6FRuHZimQcLB1rCTKpGN8hdEXw0eY3kMx+/JDUntsob4a2qfSv' 'A-Za-z0-9+' | base64 -d`.

Comment: ...and, of course, the second argument to `tr` in my previous comment should be `'A-Za-z0-9+/'`. For some reason, I accidentally left the `/` out. For that particular input string (which does not contain the letter `v`) the mistake makes no difference, but it could potentially corrupt other inputs.